# How do you join two tables, while excluding data based on a condition referencing a third table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I have three tables:

- **cdr**, which contains the fields `dst` (destination), `billsec` (duration), and `calldate`
- **Intlrates**, which contains `code` (country code), and `cost` (per minute).
- and **areacode**, which contains `areacode`, `state`, and `city`.

Currently I have a statement that adds the total cost of calling to each code, below:

```
SELECT
  mapgtalkexten.Intlrates.`Code`,
  sum(mapgtalkexten.Intlrates.Cost * (cdr.billsec/60)) as totals
FROM
  cdr JOIN mapgtalkexten.Intlrates ON    
  ((`Code` = SUBSTRING(dst, 4, 3) or `Code` = SUBSTR(dst, 4, 2))
   and dst like "011%")
  --The above limits the join to only calls where the destination phone number
  --requires the exit code (011) and the country code is 2 or 3 digits    
  or (`Code` = SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) and dst like "1%")
  --The above was written to also join countries where the NANP format was used
  --(i.e. +1787 for Puerto Rico.)    
WHERE
  cdr.calldate like "2012-11%"
  and billsec >0
GROUP BY
  mapgtalkexten.Intlrates.`Code`
```

A sample of the output:

```
Code | totals
--------------
212  | 2.035
240  | 170.76
352  | 2.268
49   | 0.45
```

Now, my problem is this: the `Intlrates` table makes no difference between NANP and non-NANP codes. Which means that in my join, both:

`011212` (morocco) and `1212` (new york) both get added to the totals. The first one is fine, the second one adds to the totals when it shouldn't.

In order to avoid this, is there way modify the second condition for the join into something along the lines of:

```
`Code` = SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) AND SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) != areacode.areacode
```

Basically making it so that it will only join if the code matches AND the code isn't in the national areacode table.

I think there's a way to do this with joins (or perhaps exists), but I'm woefully inadequate when it comes to databases and have absolutely no idea about how I would even go about implementing it. Sorry if there's more information you need/this question is nonsensical.

Comment: BTW. using `LIKE` is a computational burden (string comparisons + wildcards). Your `cdr.calldate like "2012-11%"` could be rewritten as `YEAR(cdr.calldate) = 2012 AND MONTH(cdr.calldate) = 11`. There is also an opportunity for optimisation because you can declare some extra indexes on your table one for the year and one for the month even if they are both derived from the values in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

When using the wild card column selector `*` you get all of the columns for all of the tables used in the join operation. If you specify which tables the wild card allows `t1.*, t2.*` you only get the columns from those tables.

Knowing that you can select information from two tables even if you joined (and filtered) three tables.

```
SELECT        t1.*,
              t2.*
    FROM      table_1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2
        ON    /*clauses*/
    LEFT JOIN table_3 AS t3
        ON    /*clauses*/
    WHERE    t3.column = value;
```

Comment: Your post just got marked a "low quality". This is probably because you haven't explained your answer, which could be considerably improved by explaining why it answers the question. The reason I'm saying this is I also can't read your code at all... the whitespace is really confusing.

Comment: Yes, I did... it's personal preference but I find it difficult to read. Others, of course, might not.

Comment: I don't see how your response helps me at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a HAVING statement at the end of your SELECT, as follows

```
HAVING `Code` = SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) AND SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) != areacode.areacode
```

Comment: That's because anything used in a `HAVING` clause must be declared in the `GROUP BY` clause and AFAIK it must also be declared in the select clause.

Comment: Ah, that's right. HAVING is the not the way to go here. You should change your last OR clause as follows then: or (`Code` = SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) and dst like "1%"  AND SUBSTR(dst, 2, 3) not in (select areacode from areacode))

Answer (score -2):

You will want something like this:

```
 select results.*  
 from   
 (    
     --two table query here
 )results,third_table  
  where third_table.foo = results.bar
   --filter third table here
```

What this does is produces the result set of your first two tables, then strips records where the `third_table` condition is met.

Comment: -1 Selecting from a sub query uses more memory than using proper joins because it changes the order of the operations and does not allow the query optimizer to plan for optimizations.

Comment: @MihaiStancu That is one of the most incorrect statements I have ever read during my tenure on StackOverflow.  If the data is indexed the CBO will do what it can.  Further the use of more memory is also grossly incorrect.

Comment: AFAIK querying/joining views does not use the indexes of the base tables except under certain conditions. Select queries specifying multiple tables do get treated exactly the same as their equivalent join queries. But sub queries need to get executed beforehand and the data provided by them gets used for joining & filtering just like views - without accessing their indexes.